# Datatable isn't full width

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have 3 navs each include different table works with datatables but in second and third navs my tables are not full width. I've also tried some solutions [here](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/) but no luck.

## Screenshots

`first tab`

[image: one]

`seond tab`

[image: two]

## Code

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.dataTables.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js') }}"></script>
<script defer>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.example').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6 float-right'f><'col-sm-12 mb-3 d-flex justify-content-center'p>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-md-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-5 mt-3'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
        });
    });
</script>

{{-- trying to solve the width issue (testing) --}}
<script>
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust();
});
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try adding `style="width: 100%"` to the `table` html markup, like this: `<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">`. This is done in the examples showed on the site: [Datatables on Bootstrap 4](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) (check the HTML tab).

Comment: @D.Smania I did that as well didn't work.

Comment: Well, will be hard to guess without more code details. Try inspecting the html, maybe you find something strange or a point to investigate, or hide a column from the table of the first tab to check if the same issue exists.

Comment: @D.Smania `hide a column from the table of the first tab` how to?

Comment: Read here: [Datatables Hide Columns](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/hidden_columns.html).

Answer (score 3):

This one works for me.

```
<style>
    div#DataTables_Table_0_wrapper {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```